# Null reference exception when trying to delete a "MeetingRequest" message in Outlook REST API

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to move a message to the DeletedItems folder. My request looks like this

> POST
>   https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/AAMkADNjZDVkNTljLTMwNmEtNDM1Yi1iZjgyLTAwNTgzYzBmNDc4NQBGAAAAAADwJW0rZtALTZ4Uu7_1UsU3BwBGSE8dc8m8SYGboVROeF8MAAAAAAEKAABGSE8dc8m8SYGboVROeF8MAACUQ60PAAA=/move
>
> {"DestinationId":"DeletedItems"}

And the response is

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
>           "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>       } }

A get request to the message returns the message. I think the problem might be that it is a meeting request message created by me ("MeetingMessageType": "MeetingRequest"). Is it the case that I can delete meeting request messages from other people but not my own?

here is how the message looks like:

{
    "Id": "AAMkADNjZDVkNTljLTMwNmEtNDM1Yi1iZjgyLTAwNTgzYzBmNDc4NQBGAAAAAADwJW0rZtALTZ4Uu7_1UsU3BwBGSE8dc8m8SYGboVROeF8MAAAAAAEKAABGSE8dc8m8SYGboVROeF8MAACUQ60PAAA=",
    "CreatedDateTime": "2017-07-06T12:01:37Z",
    "LastModifiedDateTime": "2017-07-06T12:06:34Z",
    "ChangeKey": "CwAAABYAAABGSE8dc8m8SYGboVROeF8MAACUVif6",
    "Categories": [],
    "ReceivedDateTime": "2017-07-06T12:01:38Z",
    "SentDateTime": "2017-07-06T12:01:38Z",
    "HasAttachments": false,
    "InternetMessageId": "",
    "Subject": "test test",
    "BodyPreview": "",
    "Importance": "Normal",
    "ParentFolderId": "AQMkADNjZDVkNTljLTMwNmEtNDM1Yi1iZjgyLTAwADU4M2MwZjQ3ODUALgAAA-AlbStm0AtNnhS7v7VSxTcBAEZITx1zybxJgZuhVE54XwwAAAIBCgAAAA==",
    "ConversationId": "AAQkADNjZDVkNTljLTMwNmEtNDM1Yi1iZjgyLTAwNTgzYzBmNDc4NQAQADZTzPctHtlCvZkjxZlRlYM=",
    "IsDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
    "IsReadReceiptRequested": false,
    "IsRead": true,
    "IsDraft": false,
    "WebLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADNjZDVkNTljLTMwNmEtNDM1Yi1iZjgyLTAwNTgzYzBmNDc4NQBGAAAAAADwJW0rZtALTZ4Uu7%2B1UsU3BwBGSE8dc8m8SYGboVROeF8MAAAAAAEKAABGSE8dc8m8SYGboVROeF8MAACUQ60PAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
    "InferenceClassification": "Focused",
    "MeetingMessageType": "MeetingRequest",
...

Comment: Do you mean that you are the organizer of the meeting?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your server side logs, this appears to be a known issue that was just fixed last night.  We will be backporting and rolling out the fix over the next few days.

It has nothing to do with the fact that it is a meeting request and/or created by you. From the Exchange store's point of view, an item is an item is an item :)